# how to write a team scheduling program in Java

Tags: java, scheduling

I would like someone to give me some ideas how to to write this program in Java. I *don't want people to write code* for me, but guide me on how to start and what methods/design should be used to get this program done. I'm new in Java and this is a programming practice for me.

My idea for the program is a simple team scheduling program, which allows users to enter numerous teams and generate the schedule for each team. In the schedule, each team will play against each other once only.

*e.g. 4 teams*

> Team 1 vs Team 2
>   Team 3 vs Team 4
>   ------------------------
>   Team 1 vs Team 3
>   Team 2 vs Team 4
>   ------------------------
>   Team 1 vs Team 4
>   Team 2 vs Team 3

My question is should I use an Array to store all the teams? How should I generate the schedule (use the Random class)? How can I make sure that each team will play against each other *once*, and not multiple times?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First you should decide exactly what you want- how will input work, what should your output look like? Another tip- I would avoid using the Random class to generate matches, although you could do it that way. You didn't just pick random matches to generate your example did you? There's a systematic way you can code it, pretty much the same as the way you generated the example in your head. Maybe try drawing it out, maybe with more teams, and looking for a pattern.

Comment: And agreeing with ahmet, you've gotten some good answers to past questions- make sure you click the Accepted button on the best one, or people will be reluctant to help you any more!

Comment: @ahment/Rob: I understand the sentiment. Another pov is that STO is a resource for anyone connected to the network.  OP may or may not be socially responsible (in the sense of the STO community's norms) but that should not prevent others from getting some possibly useful info.

Comment: Additionally SO (SE in general) isn't about getting as many points as possible. It's about helping each other, helping and sharing information in a managed way. Moreover, a question isn't private to the OT, anyone can have a similar/related problem/question. Even if the question doesn't get accepted, the votes hopefully should indicate that it's correct.

Comment: A more complex form of this problem is the [Traveling Tournament Problem](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e529), where there are additional constraints, such as a team should play no more than 3 sequential away matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few basic ideas:

Of course you need a Team object. And you need a Schedule object. Then I would recommend a couple of implementation choices from the Design Patterns book. One would be to use the Builder pattern. You would have a ScheduleMaker and then you could have different concrete builders. For instance, in Football, there are rules about the schedule: each team is going to play 2 games against each peer in its division. Generally different concrete Builders are used to provide for different physical variances. For example, in the Go4 book, the example is of a MazeBuilder where simple and complex implementations contain different numbers of doors, halls, etc. In your case, you would want to have perhaps different rule-oriented ways of making the schedule. For the example I gave, you would push a method called 'setupDivisionalGames' into the interface, then you could fill the rest of the schedule with randomly selected rivals who are not from within the division. (Builder is generally buildA, buildB... getProduct().)

If this is starting to sound like another pattern, a simpler implementation would be to just have a Strategy pattern for picking opponents. If you don't have rules like the one above, then a simple random Strategy would be a good default implementation and if you wanted to get more fancy, you could just unit test a new implementation and change no other code and get new schedules.

Finally, think about the possibility of doing a score-based approach. That's how the NFL works. If you are the Detroit Lions, your schedule is going to be more cush than if you are the Packers this coming season. Either Builder or Strategy would let you do something like that pretty easily: the team's relative score must be close to the average score of all opponents, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

1) implementation details: wait just yet.  You don't know how you are approaching the logical solution.

2) The fact that each team must play against every other team in the tournament is deterministic.  What is entirely up to you is how you distribute the games over a time period.  For example, how many consecutive games per day for a given team? Given a certain set of rules, naturally you *may* then opt for a random selection given n choices for a slot (or you may just pick the first item in .. [see answer #1]).

3) [Read up on permutations and combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) if this material is new to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Team object which holds data about the team. One team object for each team. It may also be useful to have a Match object where you can pass in two Team objects so they can play against each other. You can write a method outside of the Team and Match objects to auto generate the teams competing in the matches.

I would use an ArrayList of Team objects and then if you want random matches just generate two random numbers that would be an index in the ArrayList. You can use Math.random() or the Random class, doesn't matter. The two numbers should not be the same otherwise a team would be playing itself which doesn't make sense. You should be able to work out the algorithm in code from this.

Hope this helps.